# Laravel accessing properties through pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make an application where a user can have a variable number of profile fields, with data. So the site admin can add for example, `location`, to the list of fields, then all users with have `location` in their model.

Here is my database

```
Table  : users
Columns: id | name | email
Sample : 1  | Adam | example@example.com

Table  : user_custom_field
Columns: id | slug | name
Sample : 1  | location | Location

Table  : user_custom_data
Columns: id | user_id | field_id | data
Sample : 1  | 1       | 1        | United Kingdom
```

I've tried things like post processing the hasMany but can only get it working for 1 result, I can't get it working for all the users.

Ideally I'd like to access a custom field such as `location` like:

```
$user->location
```

or

```
$user->custom->location
```

Here is my non working Model so far...

```
public function custom()
{
    $custom_data = $this->hasMany('App\User_Custom_Data', 'user_id', 'id')
                        ->join('user_custom_field', 'user_custom_data.field_id', '=', 'user_custom_field.id');
    return $custom_data;
}
```

Am I heading down the wrong track here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you only problems here is with the naming of the tables and Eloquent models. Because you have very specific tables names I suggest that in all of these models you declare the table:

protected $table = "table_name";
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage

If you do that then you will have a lot of available from Eloquent. I might not be 100% because I'm not sure about your names at the moment, however, your User.php (User eloquent model) can have this method:

```
public function customAttributes()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\User_Custom_Data');
}
```

**don't forget that in your model User_Custom_Data.php you need to add

```
protected $table = "user_custom_data";
```

If you as above you do not need to specify whihc columns to use for the relationship.

Also, please note that the naming best practice for classes and objects is PascalCase (every new word including the first has the first letter in caps - no underscores)

Good luck :)

Comment: I'm already using the `$table` variable, it's like that because I used a generator to generate all the models and migrations from a drawing, http://www.laravelsd.com I do however want to change everything to how it should be done!

Comment: Okay. Then you can add the method to your User model instead of the one you had and you should be fine :)